# Angular2 using routerOutlet

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, components

I'm struggling trying to extend a angular2 app, generated using yo fountain-webapp. The problem I'm hitting is that I can't run  to render templates inside.

I'm new to angular2 and I've just started reading the docs as well as some example apps. I noticed there is a chance to get different components rendered into main app template file, which is exactly what I'm looking for.

For some reason however I can't get this working.

I've have this code in main.html

```
`<div class="main-container">
  <fountain-header></fountain-header>
  <main class="main">
    <fountain-title></fountain-title>
    <fountain-techs></fountain-techs>
    <some-selector></some-selector>
    <!-- Router Outlet -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6-offset4">
    <fountain-footer></fountain-footer>
  </div>
</div>`
```

**main.js**:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'fountain-app',
  template: require('./main.html'),
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class MainComponent {}`
```

**routes.js**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {MainComponent} from './main';
import {SomeComponent} from './some';

@Component({
  selector: 'fountain-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class RootComponent {}

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'some',
    component: SomeComponent
  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

and **some** component, which I want to be rendered inside main as well as any new components added depending route

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-selector',
  template: require('./some.html'),
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor() {
    this.title = "Holla molaa!";
    this.description = 'this is the description';
  }
}
```